# File Uploads Not Being Stored in Entry ID Folder

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

I've created a File Upload Directory called Films where images for Film Channel Entries are stored. The upload works and displays correctly in my templates, but I noticed in the Upload Directory that the uploaded images are being stored in the root of the directory and not in the entry's Channel ID folder.

The Channel ID folders are being created but the images are being stored outside of it ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XgLn.png)). Is this how it is supposed to work or is something buggy going on? I'm using EE 2.4.0.

Comment: It looks like you're using Channel Images, is that correct?

Comment: For a different channel entry field, but not this specific File Upload field. The only field that's able to upload to the films directory is a File field type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native EE file uploads do not use sub folders within the upload directory nor can the native file manger and uploader see any subfolders. Channel Images does create Channel ID sub folders so that is creating your Channel ID folders when you upload something to that Channel Images field (based on your comment above).

It's a big fat pain, and something that I've always been annoyed about with native uploads, but that is the way things are.